# Fix incorrectly displayed encoding on an html document with php

Tags: php, encoding, phpquery

Is there a way to fix the characters that display improperly after running this html markup through phpquery::newDocument? There are slated double quotes around -Classics with modern Woman- in the original document that end up displaying improperly after creating the new doc with phpquery.

```
    //Original document is UTF-8 encoded
$raw_html = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head><body><p>Mr. Smith of Bangkok celebrated the “Classics with modern Woman”.</p></body></html>';
print($raw_html);

$aNew_document = phpQuery::newDocument($raw_html);
print($aNew_document);
```

Original Output:
Mr. Smith of Bangkok celebrated the “Classics with modern Woman”.

New Document Output: Mr. Smith of Bangkok celebrated the �Classics with modern Woman.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. You need to save the page with `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding.
2. Add this header on top of your script:

   `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");`

**[EDIT]: How to Save Files as UTF-8 without BOM :**

On OP request, here's how you can do on Windows:

1. Download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download). It is an awesome text-editor that you should be using.
2. Install it.
3. open the PHP script in Notepad++ that contains this code. The page where you are doing all the coding. Yes, that file on your computer.
4. In Notepad++, from the Encoding menu at the top, select "Convert to UTF-8 without BOM".
5. Save the file.
6. Upload to your webserver by FTP or whatever you use.
7. Now, run that script.

Comment: +1 because I've had this problem before when I used to be on Windows.... this is Windows saving files as CP1251 (or whatever the code page). Everything should always be saved as UTF-8 and content sent also using UTF-8. Linux doesn't have this problem :)

Comment: Tried adding -header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");- at the top of the script, but it didn't fix it. Can you articulate what you mean by page being saved in this example? I don't think the page is ever saved, but exists in memory on the linux server before getting recreated by phpquery::newdocument(). If possible can you show how to insert this code properly? Or how to save the document with the correct encoding? I may be doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: @acidjazz, I have updated the answer on how to save as UTF-8 without BOM. By saying. "save the page", I mean save the file that has the code in UTF-8 without BOM mode.

Comment: @shamittomar - +1 Good tool thanks. I can see using this as a companion to eclipse. 
My real problem is that I'm using $raw_html = file_get_contents($webpage_url); to get the html. In this case the file never gets saved. This is my fault for not specifying that in the original post. The special encoded chars are fine in $raw_html. When I pass the $raw_html into phpquery::newdocument the character encoding issue surfaces.

Comment: @acidjazz, You need to save the file that has the code `$raw_html = file_get_contents($webpage_url);` with UTF-8 wihtout BOM and put the `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");` as its first line. Did you try this ? file_get_contents is UTF-8 compliant.

Comment: @shamittomar, tried saving the php file as UTF-8 without BOM but phpquery still returns weird characters. Even tried adding the charset to phpquery -$aNew_document = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($raw_event_html, $charset = 'utf-8');- but the issue persists. This may be an issue in phpquery...Thinking about using XML instead.

Comment: @acidjazz, try phpQuery::newDocumentHTML(utf8_encode($raw_event_html), 'utf-8'); then. It must be the other page that is not properly UTF-8 encoded then.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem but when i added

```
ob_start();
```

to first line

```
ob_end_flush();
```

to the end it seem to be working

Answer (score 1):

You have this in the `<head>` element:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

The next course would be to use HTML entities to display these characters.

Comment: this won't solve the problem if the file itself is not saved as UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem using phpQuery class. Problem IS as mentioned above, in top voted answer - script file is saved as UTF8-with BOM.

As i had no no chance getting notepad++ on mac osX,

every output i prepared like this `utf8_decode()`

BOM is meant for MS-windows.