# Unexpected output on file include

Tags: php, utf-8, include, byte-order-mark

I've been working on a custom CMS in PHP and haven't run into any problems until recently.  When testing, I've noticed that the string `ï»¿` has started appearing at the top of only the index page.  Testing with some die statements throughout the code, it seems the output is coming between a file include.

File A

```
<?php
if (!defined('IN_CMS'))
{
    exit;
}

require(INCLUDE_PATH . '/pages/homepage/main.php');
?>
```

File B (Included File)

```
<?php
if (!defined('IN_CMS'))
{
    exit;
}

$db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "categories` active = 1");
$cats = $db->sql_results();
$categories = array();

foreach($cats as $cat)
{
    $cat_info = array(
        'name' => $cat['name'],
        'description' => $cat['description'],
        'image' => $setting['site_url'] . '/thumbnails/' . $cat['image'],
    );

    $categories[] = $cat_info;
}

include theme('index');
?>
```

I can't understand where the output is coming from, but it seems to be somewhere between the two files.  I've added `ob_start()` right before the include line in File A and `ob_end_clean()` at the very beginning of the included file and the output does not show up, however there is no stray output anywhere in the two files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save the file with encoding `UTF-8 without BOM`.

The UTF-8 BOM is a sequence of bytes (EF BB BF) that allows the reader to identify the file as an UTF-8 file. Normally, the BOM is used to signal the endianness of the encoding, but since UTF-8 doesn't have any encoding issue, the BOM is unnecessary.

**How to do it:**

Download a good Text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and using that convert and save your file with the `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding.

[Here's a link to my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589358/fix-incorrectly-displayed-encoding-on-an-html-document-with-php/3589367#3589367) detailing how to install and convert a file encoding using Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks.  I am currently using Notepad++, just realized I accidentally changed my encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Some editors have the options to save with a BOM. Try saving the file in a different editor and uploading it, or finding the bom setting and disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

it's called BOM and probably your editor putted it there when saving the file. maybe you should look for a UTF8 WHITHOUT BOM option in your editor.