# phpQuery making Â of &nbsp; and others

Tags: chars, phpquery

When I have a file that I run through phpQuery that has stuff like `&nbsp;` or `&copy;` in it somehow a Â is added.

so when I have this file (hello.html):

```
hello, this is a test &copy;
```

and I run this code:

```
$f = phpQuery::newDocumentFile( 'hello.html' );
echo $f->html();
```

I get the following output:

```
hello, this is a test Â©
```

Is there something I can do to fic this?

Comment: Try saving your PHP file with UTF-8 without BOM encoding. You can do this with an editor like Notepad++

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589358/fix-incorrectly-displayed-encoding-on-an-html-document-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Â shows up because of encoding issues, I would try converting it from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 using `utf8_encode`

```
$markup = file_get_contents('hello.html');
$utf8_markup = utf8_encode($markup);
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($utf8_markup);
```

This is a related post [HTML encoding issues - “Â” character showing up instead of “ ”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)

Comment: sorry, but did you read the question? Let me explain: phpQuery is a library, if I let a page run through that I get these unwanted results. This has nothing to do with htmlentities...

Comment: I should have read the question better, I'm not positive if I have the answer but I added to my post above, I would try that out