# using php namespace I get a blank page

Tags: php, namespaces

The following simple code produces a blank page.

```
<?php

namespace aname;

echo "Hello world";

?>
```

Why?

Comment: What version of PHP is installed?

Comment: enable `display_errors`.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home1/cjimenez/public_html/crishk/supercore.php on line 3

Comment: What's the error there?

Comment: So you don't have php 5.4. You have php < 5.3.

Comment: Just ran into the exact same issue... just to let you know that it's a valid question : ) The issue seems to be with an error occurring, but somehow the error doesn't bubble up.

Comment: as per @Jacco I had the same issue, errors turned on and correct php but still blank page but LOG showed issue "PHP Fatal error:  Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just now. The solution was to convert the php-file encoding to UTF-8 without BOM.

You can read about it here: [Fix incorrectly displayed encoding on an html document with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589358/fix-incorrectly-displayed-encoding-on-an-html-document-with-php) and here: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you haven't actually installed PHP, or at least not correctly.
Make sure that it's in your C:\ drive and that you followed the instillation instructions. If you used the installer, then try uninstalling then reinstalling and it should fix itself

Peace!

Comment: If you read the comments, then you'll notice that the OP is receiving PHP parser errors, so PHP _is_ installed. I'm 99.9% confident that the OP simply has an outdated PHP version in use as already mentioned by @Leggendario.